# Testing Samba server on host machine results in NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE

Tags: server, samba, 19.04

Running `smbclient -L localhost` on the Samba server host machine returns:

```
Unable to initialize messaging context
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE
```

Wondering if I'm doing some thing really stupid or not. Google turned up nothing. Looking for any help I can get.

Relevant information listed below. Let me know if there's anything else I can provide.

---

Server is running `Ubuntu 19.04 Live Server` with `Samba 4.10.0`.

`systemctl status smbd.service` and `systemctl status nmbd.service` both return `Active: active (running)` and `Status: *mbd: ready to serve connections...` so it seems like they're running fine.

Using the server's local IP address from `ifconfig` (i.e. `192.168.1.xxx`) instead of `localhost` doesn't work.

Adding `client max protocol = SMB3` to the global config settings does nothing. `server max protocol = SMB3` already seems to be a default. Adding `client min protocol = SMB3` and `server min protocol = SMB3` in addition to the client max line doesn't work either.

Running `smbclient -L localhost` as root results in the `Unable to initialize messaging context` line disappearing, but the `protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE` line still gets printed.

Filesystem for the relevant directory is a ZFS zpool, made up of a striped mirror of four HDDs. `zfs set sharesmb=on` and `zfs set sharenfs=on` was set for all filesystems.

Network interface is `eno1`, but adding that to the config file with `interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0 eno1` and `bind interfaces only = yes` does nothing.

Don't think it matters here since this step isn't even reached, but samba account passwords were created for all user accounts already using `smbpasswd`.

Don't think it matters here either, but `ufw` is configured with `ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/16 to any app Samba`, but disabling `ufw` outright also doesn't help anyway.

`/etc/samba/smb.conf` file:

```
[global]
   workgroup = REDACTEDGROUP
   server string = REDACTED Samba Server v%v @ %h
   hide unreadable = yes
   read only = no
   hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/16
   hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   logging = file
   map to guest = Bad User
   max log size = 1000
   obey pam restrictions = Yes
   pam password change = Yes
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   server role = standalone server
   unix password sync = Yes
   usershare allow guests = Yes
   idmap config * : backend = tdb

[REDACTEDBox]
   comment = REDACTED file hosting
   path = /box/REDACTED
   valid users = @groupa, @groupb, @wheel
   write list = @groupa, @wheel
   read list = @groupb
   guest ok = no
   create mask = 0774
   directory mask = 0775

[PublicBox]
   comment = REDACTED public file hosting
   path = /box/public
   guest ok = yes
   create mask = 0775
   directory mask = 0775
```

`testparm` on the config file revealed no issues.

Answer (score 5):

I added -m SMB3 to the smbclient command and the problem has disappeared.
I found the solution here: https://github.com/dperson/samba#troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Just to add the original explanation linked in the answer from @hugues-antoine-rabany, which worked for me (sorry, still cannot comment):

> Attempting to connect with the smbclient commandline tool. By default
> samba still tries to use SMB1, which is depriciated and has security
> issues. This container defaults to SMB2, which for no decernable
> reason even though it's supported is disabled by default so run the
> command as smbclient -m SMB3, then any other options you would
> specify.